# Customize information in sales order email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, shipping-address, order-email

I have a custom **customer/address** attribute `store_id`, I want to add it in my  **Shipping Information:** in sales email template, I know that currently it gets shipping address from

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

in function

```
 public function getShippingAddress()
{
    foreach ($this->getAddressesCollection() as $address) {
        if ($address->getAddressType()=='shipping' && !$address->isDeleted()) {
            return $address;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Currently my Address look like this

```
Abdul Ghaffar, Street 10
Islamabad, Punjab, 44000
Pakistan
T: 123456789
```

I am unable to find where this format is being created, I want to look address like

```
store_id -
Abdul Ghaffar, Street 10
Islamabad, Punjab, 44000
Pakistan
T: 123456789
```

where `store_id` is my custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieved the value of this field and pass it as a param in the following function

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php**

```
  public function sendNewOrderEmail()
    {
     /*Existing Code*/
     if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getCustomerId());
            $companyname = $customerId->getCompanyname();
            $storeID = $customerId->getStoreId();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getCustomerId());
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
            $storeID = $customerId->getStoreId(); // fetch your custom attribute
        }

        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
          'order'        =>  $this,
          'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
          'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
          'storeid'  => $storeID 
       ));
     }
```

After making this change. edit Transactional Email to include this param. 
       Go to System > Transactional Emails > New Order Email and add like below :

```
 {{ var storeid }}
 {{var order.getShippingAddress.format('html')}}
```

hen this would get displayed in your Order Email in 'Shipping Address' Information right at the Start

**P.S.** I would advice you to override the core blocks instead of making changes in the core

Comment: As you said, I am doing $storeID ='AG';'$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order' => $this,
                'billing' => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'store_id' => $storeID
                    )
            );' and in template it is like '{{ var store_id }}
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}', I am getting in my email is "{{ var store_id }} Abdul Ghaffar, Street 10"

Comment: this will not work until you remove space from ** {{ var storeid }}**, I mean it should be ** {{var storeid}}**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change it create new phtml file and add your format this function is used many places. simply add you phtml like that in your email template..

```
 {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipping.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Comment: This is also right, but I have solved my issue by @Manashvi birla answer

Answer (score 1):

You can change address format defined by default in the in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/config.xml`. Go to `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates` and add the custom attribute where you want. Result should looks like this:

```
{{depend store_id}}Store ID{{var store_id}}{{/depend}}
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}} ....
```

You can find additional info [here (pt. 3-5)](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/)

Note: The attribute should be present in the `sales/order_address` and `sales/quote_address`, in order to display correctly on all the stages.

#### Example:

Add attribute:

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_store_id', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Custom Store No#',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_store_id')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();

/**
 * Adding Extra Column to sales_flat_order_address
 * to store the delivery instruction field
 */
$sales_order_address = $installer->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'custom_store_id', array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Custom Store Id'
    ));

$sales_quote_address = $installer->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'custom_store_id', array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Custom Store Id'
    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Add fieldset:

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_address>
        <custom_store_id>
            <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
        </custom_store_id>
    </sales_convert_quote_address>
</fieldsets>
```

Modify format:

```
Before {{depend custom_store_id}}Store ID{{var custom_store_id}} After

{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

Get result:
[image: Result]

#### Update:

Variables to the template come from the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::getProcessedTemplate()`:

```
/**
 * Process email template code
 *
 * @param   array $variables
 * @return  string
 */
public function getProcessedTemplate(array $variables = array())
{
    $processor = $this->getTemplateFilter();
    $processor->setUseSessionInUrl(false)
        ->setPlainTemplateMode($this->isPlain());

    if (!$this->_preprocessFlag) {
        $variables['this'] = $this;
    }

    if (isset($variables['subscriber']) && ($variables['subscriber'] instanceof Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber)) {
        $processor->setStoreId($variables['subscriber']->getStoreId());
    }

    // Apply design config so that all subsequent code will run within the context of the correct store
    $this->_applyDesignConfig();

    // Populate the variables array with store, store info, logo, etc. variables
    $variables = $this->_addEmailVariables($variables, $processor->getStoreId());

    $processor
        ->setTemplateProcessor(array($this, 'getTemplateByConfigPath'))
        ->setIncludeProcessor(array($this, 'getInclude'))
        ->setVariables($variables);

    try {
        // Filter the template text so that all HTML content will be present
        $result = $processor->filter($this->getTemplateText());
        // If the {{inlinecss file=""}} directive was included in the template, grab filename to use for inlining
        $this->setInlineCssFile($processor->getInlineCssFile());
        // Now that all HTML has been assembled, run email through CSS inlining process
        $processedResult = $this->getPreparedTemplateText($result);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)   {
        $this->_cancelDesignConfig();
        throw $e;
    }
    $this->_cancelDesignConfig();

    return $processedResult;
}
```

where the `$processor->filter($this->getTemplateText());` calls callback functions (methods) one by one and replace a clause "{{...}}" by the result.

Address render comes from the `Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default::render()`. Customer attributes comes from the `Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributes()`:

```
$attributes = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getAttributes();
```

So, if you get your attribute in the array from the method `Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributes()`, you can call it in the address template using this: `{{var attributeName}}`. The `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::varDirective()` method collects all variables and stores them in the array `_templateVars`. Method `Varien_Filter_Template::_getVariable()` finally replaces a variables from the `_templateVars` array.

Comment: Will try this, but how **orig_template_variables** field is being set in **core_email_template** table

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar I’ve updated my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: got it, my issue is solved,